# QlikView ActiveDocument.NoOfSheets not working

Tags: scripting, qlikview

I created a new qlikview doc and in the script I just wanted to know the no of sheets. So I wrote

```
iNumSheets = ActiveDocument.NoOfSheets;
iVar = 2;

FOR t = 0 to  iNumSheets
    iVar = 4;
NEXT
```

I get the following error

```
Script line error: 
FOR t = 0 to  iNumSheets
```

What am I missing? I am a programmers for years and these simple things often drive me nuts in qlikview. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are using the Load Script editor for your code, rather than the Module Editor.

You can access the module editor using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

You will need to remove the semicolons at the end of your code lines and also enclose your code with `Sub` and `End Sub` if you are using VBScript as the lanuage for the code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since the for loop counter is starting from 0 you'll have to do `iNumSheets - 1` i.e., `for t = 0 to iNumSheets - 1`.

You can try the below code to loop over the visible sheets which avoids the additional step.

**Code**

```
for i = 0 to ActiveDocument.NoOfSheets - 1
your code...
next
```

Comment: strange, please try LET to assign value to variable.